# How to combine a sql query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

```
sql = "SELECT * " +                   
      "FROM memberTable " +
      "WHERE Hometown = 'St.Pete, FL' AND " +
      "DELETE Relationship FROM memberTable WHERE Relationship ='self'"+
      "ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC, Relationship, Hometown;";
```

Here is my code, I am writing a program that will delete relationship "self" and show `Hometown = "St.Pete, FL"`. I can't figure out how to add the to `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: `Delete` and `Select` are two different queries.  Have 1 for each

Comment: or just do something like SELECT * .... ; DELETE .....; . The result will come back as DataSet

Answer (score 0):

```
sql =
                "SELECT * " +
                "FROM memberTable " +
                "WHERE Hometown = 'St.Pete, FL' AND Relationship <> 'self'" +
                "ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC;";
```

This is what I finally got it to work!!!

Comment: what about delete ?

Comment: If you did not want to delete the data but just not present data with that relationship... then why you asked the question....

Comment: I am sorry I thought I had to delete it, but in reality it just dd not need to be included. I am still new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```C#
var deleteQuery = @" DELETE Relationship FROM memberTable WHERE Relationship ='self'";
var selectQuery = @"SELECT * FROM memberTable WHERE Hometown = 'St.Pete, FL' ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC, Relationship, Hometown";
var combinedQuery = string.Format("{0};{1}", deleteQuery, selectQuery);
```